# Trying to mount and recover data from a DVD/recorder HDD

Tags: linux, command-line, external-hdd, dvd

I have a old DVD/HDD recorder (Panasonic DMR-EH58) with RCA inputs & outputs etc. I want to recover all the recordings off its HDD. The HDD is a 2008 ATA/IDE 7200RPM Hitachi deskstar Model no:HDP725025GLAT80 250 GB has a DVD drive.

It has been used at a conference center for many years recording camera RCA input. It is in good condition but it is outdated so I am trying to copy the recordings to a computer. I also would like to recover the deleted files if possible as they would not have been overwritten yet.

I have borrowed a universal drive adapter and tried to mount it on both Windows 8.1 and ChaletOS Linux (Ubuntu based XFCE type distro). Windows showed it as a grayed F: drive and Linux did not auto mount it either.

GParted shows it as "/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label":
[image: GParted]

Command line attempts follow:

```
joel@joel-laptop:~$ mount dev/sdb
mount: dev/sdb: No such file or directory

joel@joel-laptop:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/usbdisk
[sudo] password for joel: 
mount: special device /dev/sdb does not exist

joel@joel-laptop:~$ mount dev/sdb
mount: dev/sdb: No such file or directory

joel@joel-laptop:~$ ls -alh /dev/disk/by-path/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Apr 30 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Apr 30 18:41 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Apr 30 21:31 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part6 -> ../../sda6
```

- Root directory is dev/sda5
- Swap is dev/sda6
- Windows is dev/sda1
- Spare data partition is dev/sda2

Looks like an unsupported file system error...

Comment: What happens if you point TestDisk at the device?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you should always say `/dev` and not just `dev`.

Comment: DVD/HDD recorders often use their own formats on the HDD, and on top of that encrypt the content. So you need quite a bit of reverse engineering to get your recordings from that HDD. Yes, the copyright industry sucks.

Comment: If you are unable to mount it as a filesystem you can still use some tools (`PhotoRec` included in `TestDisk`, or `foremost` or `Scalpel`) that will scan the raw bytes for known media files, if the recorder did indeed record things in standard formats. It will obviously not work if the content is scrambled or crypted in any way. Have a look here for ideas: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Recovery

Answer (score 0):

I found out these links to be related to your problem, without guarantee :

- http://www.avsforum.com/forum/106-dvd-recorders-standard-def/1010518-panasonic-dmr-hard-drive-data-recovery-can-done.html
- http://www.yodot.com/hard-drive-recovery/panasonic-dmr-hard-drive-data-recovery.html

Of course, and especially since you said you need to work with deleted files, you need to copy the whole content (on a byte level) before doing any forensics on it.